# How to set authentication access to Swagger Docs via Oauth2 on Flask?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, swagger, blueprint

I have a Flask App(not Restful.Api), and I have a working docs route that shows swagger.json(documentataion to all my routes).
[Here is a screenshot of API documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrrKE.png)
What I am asking is how to restrict access to that route.
Here is my code where I implement get_swagger_blueprint and regiester_blueprint methods.

```
flask_app.register_blueprint(get_swaggerui_blueprint(SWAGGER_URL,
                                                     DOC_URL,
                                                     config={'app_name': "Seans-Python-Flask-REST-Boilerplate"}),
                                                     url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)
```

Could anyone, please, tell me how to modify **swagger.json** file and what to add to my **code sample**.

I want to use Flask App, not Flask Restful Api.
Thanks!